# Can we use CSS variable in different css files

Tags: css, css-variables

Here is the example

main.css
mobo.css

styleguide.css (Where all CSS variables are mentioned)

Can I use them in main.css and mobo.css ???

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the perfect question and how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), Complete and Verifiable Example

Answer (score 2):

"CSS variables" is the colloquial name for Custom Properties.

Like any other property, it doesn't matter where it is set from¹, only that it applies to the element. Therefore it doesn't matter which stylesheet sets the properties or which one reads it.

```html
<style>
  #foo {
    background: var(--example);
    height: 35px;
  }
</style>

<style>
  #foo {
    --example: red;
  }
</style>


<div id="foo">
</div>
```

---

Footnotes

1. If multiple sources try to set the same property then it might start to matter since document order is one of the decision points when calculating the [cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade) order.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just link your file with all the variables in the HTML

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="var.css">
```

Or if you are using SASS, in your main css file you can do :

```css
@import('file.css');
```